# Can I use ClockKit with a custom background image and complications at the same time?

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2, watchos, clockkit

I would like to use a watch face with a custom image (as shown during the WWCD'15 keynote) and, at the same time, show complications. How can I do this?

I have studied the `ClockKit` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/ClockKit/Reference/ClockKit_framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016082) but could not find a way to do this.

Update: It seems that `watchOS 2` offers a watch face with a custom image. However, this watch face does not allow to add complications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make custom clock **face**, but you can build **complications** with ClockKit.

As you know from September 2014 event, complications are some data from other apps that you cam see them on the watch face, and they are even easier to see than Glances. For example, complications in WatchKit 1 are Activity rings, Battery Percentage, World Clock, Calendar events, etc.

There is an option in ClockKit to build complications, but you can't make watch faces.

**NOTE: The single picture watch face doesn't provide complications at all.**

Answer (score 1):

Nope, sorry. There's no support for custom clock faces in either version of WatchKit.